# How to limit impact of a bad application on MariaDB Galera Cluster with MaxScale?

Tags: mariadb, galera, mariadb-10.3, maxscale

I have a Galera Replication cluster with three MariaDB nodes where a Maxscale Active-Passive cluster in front provides a single node image to tis clients.

I have a bad behaving client, which opens connections and doesn't close them. No of connections keep increasing till database limits hit. To limit the number of connections I have configured below two params

```
max_connections=
max_user_connections=
```

My situation is this, When I have only max_connections configured, whenever the limits are reached Galera node stops accepting more connection with error of "Too many connections". When Maxscale see this connection rejections for n number of times, it puts the server under *Maintenance* mode. I can understand this behaviour, it's expected.
When I configure max_user_connections, and because the application is behaving bad and trying to make new connections continously, when the userspecific limit reaches further attempt of connections fails to the mariadb nodes in backend. Maxscale observes these failures, and again puts the server in *Maintenance* mode. I believe during this time it only sees connections attempt from the bad client, no other application tried to connect.

And this way, MaxScale puts all three nodes in *Maintenance* mode over the time, which makes complete DB service unavailable.

For me as administrator, situation becomes same, puting a user specific limit doesn't achieve anything. I would like to ask two points here

**Q1. How can I prevent just one user connection failures from puting the backend mariadb node into maintenance?**

**Q2. Any documentation, or tutorials, article reference on how and when MaxScale decides to put a server in Maintenance mode?**

Below are the details about the environment

> Galera - 25.3.23,
> MariaDB - 10.3.12,
> MaxScale - 2.4.11,
> OS - RHEL 7.4 (Maipo)

Here is my configuration

**MariaDB Galera Configuration**

```
[server]

# this is only for the mysqld standalone daemon
[mysqld]
#user statistics
userstat=1
performance_schema
#wait_timeout=600
max_allowed_packet=1024M
#
lower_case_table_names=1
#
max_connections=1500
max_user_connections=200
#
# * Galera-related settings
#
[galera]
# Mandatory settings
wsrep_on=ON
wsrep_provider=/usr/lib64/galera/libgalera_smm.so
wsrep_provider_options="gcache.size=300M; gcache.page_size=300M; pc.ignore_sb=false; pc.ignore_quorum=false"
#wsrep_cluster_address defines members of the cluster
wsrep_cluster_address=gcomm://x.x.x.1,x.x.x.2,x.x.x.3
wsrep_cluster_name="mariadb-cluster"
wsrep_node_address=x.x.x.1
wsrep_node_incoming_address=x.x.x.1
wsrep_debug=OFF
#
binlog_format=row
default_storage_engine=InnoDB
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=2
innodb_doublewrite=1
query_cache_size=0
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=0
innodb_buffer_pool_size=5G
#
bind-address=x.x.x.1
#
[mariadb]
#performance
wait_timeout=31536000
#
#query logging
log_output=FILE
#slow queries
slow_query_log
slow_query_log_file=/var/log/mariadb/mariadb-slow.log
long_query_time=10.0
log_queries_not_using_indexes=ON
min_examined_row_limit=1000
log_slow_rate_limit=1
log_slow_verbosity=query_plan,explain
#
#error logs
log_error=/var/log/mariadb/mariadb-error.log
log_warnings=2
```

Similarly all three Galera nodes are configured.

**MaxScale configuration**

```
[maxscale]
threads=auto

# Server definitions
[mariadb1]
type=server
address=x.x.x.1
port=3306
protocol=MariaDBBackend
#priority=0

[mariadb2]
type=server
address=x.x.x.2
port=3306
protocol=MariaDBBackend
#priority=1

[mariadb3]
type=server
address=x.x.x.3
port=3306
protocol=MariaDBBackend
#priority=1

# Monitor for the servers
#

[Galera-Monitor]
type=monitor
module=galeramon
servers=mariadb1, mariadb2, mariadb3
user=xxx
password=xxx
#disable_master_role_setting=true
monitor_interval=1000
#use_priority=true
#
disable_master_failback=true
available_when_donor=true

# Service definitions

[Galera-Service]
type=service
router=readwritesplit
master_accept_reads=true
connection_keepalive=300s
master_reconnection=true
master_failure_mode=error_on_write
connection_timeout=3600s
servers=mariadb1, mariadb2, mariadb3
user=xxx
password=xxx
#filters=Query-Log-Filter

#Listener

[Galera-Listener]
type=listener
service=Galera-Service
protocol=MariaDBClient
port=4306
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried `connection_timeout, max_connections, max_user_connections` configurations on database server nodes but it didn't help. When the bad application is making connection attempts and if it reaches threshold, database servers drop connections with `"Too many connections"`. Maxscale observes it for sometime and put the back-end servers under `Maintenance`. Setting up `max_users_connections` to some value say: 200, causes backend server to reject connections when limit reaches for a single user. Now, when there are multiple `Too many connections` failures due to 'max_users_connections`limit threshold breach due to bad application, Maxscale again marks the server in`Maintenance` state. It doesn't differentiate that the attempts are from single user or many users collectively. It just sees the 'Too many connections' failures from the server.

To solve the situation, I created a separate Service under Maxscale for the bad behaving application with the `max_connections` limit set. Created a separate listener on different port number for the service.

Due to a separate service, whenever `max_connections` threshold reaches on MAxscale other clients are unaffected. Additionally,  took care that `max_connections` limit on MariadB servers on back-end is more than the value configured on Maxscale, so threshold reaches earlier on Maxscale, and it never puts back-end servers in `Maintenance mode`. New configuration block for Maxscale is as below -

```
[Galera-Service]
type=service
router=readwritesplit
master_accept_reads=true
connection_keepalive=300s
master_reconnection=true
master_failure_mode=error_on_write
connection_timeout=300s
max_connections=2500
servers=mariadb1, mariadb2, mariadb3
user=user
password=password


[Galera-Service-Bad-App]
type=service
router=readwritesplit
master_accept_reads=true
connection_keepalive=300s
master_reconnection=true
master_failure_mode=error_on_write
connection_timeout=300s
max_connections=250
servers=mariadb1, mariadb2, mariadb3
user=user
password=password
#

[Galera-Listener]
type=listener
service=Galera-Service
protocol=MariaDBClient
port=4306

[Galera-Listener-astro]
type=listener
service=Galera-Service-Badd-App
protocol=MariaDBClient
port=4307
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think MaxScale is the component you want to use to fix this problem. It's possible to do this in the MariaDB server itself. I've experienced exactly the same problem and have solved it by imposing limits on the database users using the `max_user_connections` setting.

> wait_timeout=31536000

Why is this value so large? Do your applications keep the connections open rather than creating new ones? While that might sound like a good idea, it means that connections accidentally left open/idle won't be closed until much later.

> For me as administrator, situation becomes same, puting a user
> specific limit doesn't achieve anything.

I don't think this is correct.

> Q1. How can I prevent just one user connection failures from puting
> the backend mariadb node into maintenance?

If you limit the database users so that the sum of `max_user_connection` for all users < `max_connections` for each of the nodes, then the users will not be able to reach the `max_connections` limit.

> Q2. Any documentation, or tutorials, article reference on how and when
> MaxScale decides to put a server in Maintenance mode?

I don't think there is one single document for this, but rather it is scattered across the MaxScale documentation. I think maintenance mode started out as a way for the admin to schedule planned downtime, but has since been used for other things as well, see e.g. [maintenance_on_low_disk_space](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-maxscale-24-mariadb-monitor/#maintenance_on_low_disk_space)

Comment: I am replying it late, but still would like to add that your answer adds some information but  doesn't solve my problem